# Using VENTouchLock; how do I detect a response?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Using VENTouchLock; how do I detect a response and do something after the user has entered the right pincode?

https://github.com/venmo/VENTouchLock

Comment: With `@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^willFinishWithResult)(BOOL success);`? Did you try the sample project? How does it work?

Comment: "- (VENTouchLockEnterPasscodeViewController *)enterPasscodeVC{" is called, but  "enterPasscodeVC.willFinishWithResult = ^(BOOL success) {"  inside isn't..

Comment: It's probably called once - but not again. - The things i put inside willFinishWithResult never happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Larme said in comment above; you need to set the willFinishWithResult property.

Example:

```
VENTouchLockEnterPasscodeViewController *showPasscodeVC = [[VENTouchLockEnterPasscodeViewController alloc] init];

showPasscodeVC.willFinishWithResult = ^(BOOL success) {
   if (success) {
      //code
   }
   else {
      //code
   }
};

[self presentViewController:[showPasscodeVC embeddedInNavigationController] animated:YES completion:nil];
```